# Dynamic Vue Table

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make a dynamic table in Vue, but I'm struggling with the way I would like to show the data.

This is what I get from the API: (There are more values but I'll keep it simple.)

```
{id: 1, descricao: 'Ambiente 01', valor: "12.5"}
{id: 2, descricao: 'Ambiente 02', valor: "5.5"}
{id: 3, descricao: 'Ambiente 03', valor: "-2.5"}
{id: 4, descricao: 'Ambiente 01', valor: "12.2"}
{id: 5, descricao: 'Ambiente 02', valor: "5.2"}
{id: 6, descricao: 'Ambiente 03', valor: "-2.3"}
{id: 7, descricao: 'Ambiente 01', valor: "11.9"}
{id: 8, descricao: 'Ambiente 02', valor: "5.7"}
{id: 9, descricao: 'Ambiente 03', valor: "-2.8"}
```

This is what my vue component looks like:

```
<template>  
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th v-for="(dados, descricao) in agrupaDados" :key="dados.id">
          {{ descricao }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="dados in agrupaDados" :key="dados.id">
        <td v-for="row in dados" :key="row.id">
          {{ row.valor }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: [
      'dados'
    ],
    computed: {
      agrupaDados() {
        return _.groupBy(this.dados, 'descricao');
      }
    }   
  }
</script>
```

And this is what my table looks like: 
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPTD1.png)

The problem is that the data that corresponds to each column is being displayed in a row, and I have no clue of how to change it. In order to explain it better, I will try to ilustrate the result I'm getting and the result I would like to get...

```
What I have...

Ambiente 01 | Ambiente 02 | Ambiente 03
---------------------------------------
12.5        | 12.2        | 11.9
---------------------------------------
5.5         | 5.2         | 5.7
---------------------------------------    
-2.5        | -2.3        | -2.8

What I want...

Ambiente 01 | Ambiente 02 | Ambiente 03
---------------------------------------
12.5        | 5.5         | -2.5
---------------------------------------
12.2        | 5.2         | -2.3
---------------------------------------    
11.9        | 5.7         | -2.8
```

I appreciate if someone explains me how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the same number of elements on each column?

Comment: No! The number of elements that will come from the API depends upon what the user chooses. So, as I have now 3 columns (Ambiente 01, Ambiente 02, Ambiente 03) I could have just one, or more than 3...

Comment: I mean, do you have the the same number of row for each column? In your example, 3 rows for Ambiente 01, 3 rows for Ambiente 02 and 3 rows for Ambiente 03

Comment: Yes, each row has the same number of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<template> 
   <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th v-for="(dados, descricao) in agrupaDados">
          {{ descricao }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="row in maxRows">
        <td v-for="dados in agrupaDados">
          {{ dados[row-1] && dados[row-1].valor }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template> 
<script>
  export default {
    props: [
      'dados'
    ],
    computed: {
      agrupaDados() {
        return _.groupBy(this.dados, 'descricao');
      },
      maxRows() {
        // calculating max rows count
        return Math.max(..._.map(this.agrupaDados, (g) => g.length));
      }
    } 
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="index in (data.length / 3)">
      <td>{{ data[3 * (index - 1)].valor }}</td>
      <td>{{ data[3 * (index - 1) + 1].valor }}</td>
      <td>{{ data[3 * (index - 1) + 2].valor }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

`data.length / 3` because you have 3 different columns.

Where `data` is an array of elements like this:

```
data: [
    { id: 1, descricao: "Ambiente 01", valor: "12.5" },
    { id: 2, descricao: "Ambiente 02", valor: "5.5" },
    { id: 3, descricao: "Ambiente 03", valor: "-2.5" },
    { id: 4, descricao: "Ambiente 01", valor: "12.2" },
    { id: 5, descricao: "Ambiente 02", valor: "5.2" },
    { id: 6, descricao: "Ambiente 03", valor: "-2.3" },
    { id: 7, descricao: "Ambiente 01", valor: "11.9" },
    { id: 8, descricao: "Ambiente 02", valor: "5.7" },
    { id: 9, descricao: "Ambiente 03", valor: "-2.8" }
]
```